# Is there a efficient way to have a program execute a block of code if the input is of a multiple of a certain number?

Tags: java

I have a program that is for a blackjack game. Currently I'm using a switch construct in my card class to determine the corresponding initial deck position with the specific card, ie. if the deck position is 1. it's an ace of clubs. Since the number of cards I'm dealing with is 13 and there are 4 suits I'm dealing with multiples of 13 when entering the type of suit. Thus, is there any way to have a program execute a block of code if the input is a multiple of 13? Meaning I don't have to write individual switch cases for every input position of a deck for it's suit and card number.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking to use `x % 13`?

Comment: I'll look into it, thank you!

Comment: `if (x != 0 && x % 13 == 0)`